# Dialogflow Webhook call failed. Error: [ResourceName error] Path '' does not match template

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I am using Dialogflow ES and once I got the webhook setup, I haven't been having issues. But after a few months, I just started getting a random error. It seems to be inconsistent as in sometimes I get it for a specific web call and other times it works fine. This is from the Raw API response:

```
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 3,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: [ResourceName error] Path '' does not match template 'projects/{project_id=*}/locations/{location_id=*}/agent/environments/{environment_id=*}/users/{user_id=*}/sessions/{session_id=*}/contexts/{context_id=*}'.."
  }
```

The webhook is in GCP Functions in the same project. I have a simple "ping" function in the same agent that calls the webhook. That works properly and pings the function, records some notes in the function log (so I know the function is being called), and returns a response fine, so I know the webhook is connected and working for other intents in the same agent before and after I get the error above.

Other intents in the same agent work (and this one WAS working), but I get this error now. I also tried recreating the intent and I get the same behavior.

The project is linked to a billing account and I have been getting charged for it, so I don't think it is an issue with being on a trial or otherwise. Though the Dialogflow itself is in "trial", but the linked webhook function is billed.

Where can I find what this error means or where to look to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this with fresh eyes, I found out what was happening.
The issue was a mal-formed output context. I was returning the bad output context sometimes (which explained why sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't). Specifically, I was returning the parameters directly into the output context without the output context 'name' or 'parameters'. Everything looked like it was working and I didn't get any other errors, but apparently, when Dialogflow receives a bad web response, it generates the unhelpful error above.